Challenges with CPC Metrics in Looker Studio When Filtering Google Ads Campaign Types
I'm using Looker Studio here and when I pull metrics from Google Ads, it works... but when I select the campaign type (I created a filter in Looker so that, for example, when it says 'Mouse' it transforms into a video campaign, then I can divide it). However, when I filter by video campaign, search, demand gen, and others, the CPC simply doesn't load... the other metrics load.
I hope I can pull the CPC metrics
